# Go templates: Currency pipe format?

Tags: templates, go, format, currency

I'm trying to represent money in a go template.
{{.cash}}

But right now, cash comes as 1000000

Would it be possible to make it output 1,000,000 ?

Is there some sort of {{.cash | Currency}} formatter?
If not, how do I go about getting the desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to create a [template.Func](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) that calls a formatting function. A popular library for "humanizing" numbers is https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize (I'd love to write an example but I'm pressed for time - this should get you started!)

Comment: Go does not support grouping decimals. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020308/how-to-fmt-printf-an-integer-with-thousands-comma) is about how to do that, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31046325/1705598) shows a really efficient solution using only the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `github.com/dustin/go-humanize` to do this.

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "comma": humanize.Comma,
}
t := template.New("").Funcs(templateFuncs).Parse(`A million: {{comma .}}`)
err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, 1000000)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("execution: %s", err)
}
// A million: 1,000,000
```