# Is there a better way to insert "|' into binary string rep to get this 10|000|001

Tags: string, go, formatting

Is there a better way to insert `"|"` into a string
given a binary string representation of decimal `200 = 11001000`
this function returns a string = `11|001|000`

While this function works, it seems very kludgy!!  Why is it so
hard in GO to do a simple character insertion???

```
func (i Binary) FString() string {
    a := strconv.FormatUint(i.Get(), 2)
    y := make([]string, len(a), len(a)*2)
    data := []rune(a)
    r := []rune{}
    for i := len(data) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        r = append(r, data[i])
    }
    for j := len(a) - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
        y = append(y, string(r[j]))
        if ((j)%3) == 0 && j > 0 {
            y = append(y, "|")
        }
    }
    return strings.Join(y, "")
}
```

Comment: This is basically grouping decimals, using `|` as the separator symbol. Possible duplicate of [How to fmt.Printf an integer with thousands comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020308/how-to-fmt-printf-an-integer-with-thousands-comma).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you call better. I'd use regular expressions.

In this case, the complexity arises from inserting separators from the right. If we padded the string so that its length was a multiple of 3, we could insert the separator from the left. And we could easily use a regular expression to insert `|` before every three characters. Then, we can just strip off the leading `|` + padding.

```
func (i Binary) FString() string {
    a := strconv.FormatUint(i.Get(), 2)
    pad_req := len(a) % 3
    padding := strings.Repeat("0", (3 - pad_req))
    a = padding + a
    re := regexp.MustCompile("([01]{3})")
    a = re.ReplaceAllString(a, "|$1")
    start := len(padding) + 1
    if len(padding) == 3 {
        // If we padded with "000", we want to remove the `|` before *and* after it
        start = 5
    }
    a = a[start:]
    return a
}
```

- [Snippet on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/X0AyIe-KKv)

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not critical and you just want a compact version, you may copy the input digits to output, and insert a `|` symbol whenever a group of 2 has been written to the output.

Groups are counted from right-to-left, so when copying the digits from left-to-right, the first group might be smaller. So the counter of digits inside a group may not necessarily start from `0` in case of the first group, but from `len(input)%3`.

Here is an example of it:

```
func Format(s string) string {
    b, count := &bytes.Buffer{}, len(s)%3
    for i, r := range s {
        if i > 0 && count == i%3 {
            b.WriteRune('|')
        }
        b.WriteRune(r)
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

Testing it:

```
for i := uint64(0); i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Println(Format(strconv.FormatUint(i, 2)))
}
fmt.Println(Format(strconv.FormatInt(1234, 2)))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4Pe9QhuhJx)):

```
0
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
1|000
1|001
10|011|010|010
```

If you have to do this many times and performance does matter, then check out my answer to the question: [How to fmt.Printf an integer with thousands comma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31046325/1705598)

Based on that a fast solution can be:

```
func Format(s string) string {
    out := make([]byte, len(s)+(len(s)-1)/3)
    for i, j, k := len(s)-1, len(out)-1, 0; ; i, j = i-1, j-1 {
        out[j] = s[i]
        if i == 0 {
            return string(out)
        }
        if k++; k == 3 {
            j, k = j-1, 0
            out[j] = '|'
        }
    }
}
```

Output is the same of course. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qNMQ4Dg1ak).

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I guess I was not that far off -- Your solutions are

Comment: are better than mine in most cases  -- Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is a partitioning problem. You can use this function:

```
func partition(s, separator string, pLen int) string {
    if pLen < 1 || len(s) == 0 || len(separator) == 0 {
        return s
    }

    buffer := []rune(s)
    L := len(buffer)
    pCount := L / pLen

    result := []string{}

    index := 0
    for ; index < pCount; index++ {
        _from := L - (index+1)*pLen
        _to := L - index*pLen
        result = append(result, string(buffer[_from:_to]))
    }

    if L%pLen != 0 {
        result = append(result, string(buffer[0:L-index*pLen]))
    }

    for h, t := 0, len(result)-1; h < t; h, t = h+1, t-1 {
        result[t], result[h] = result[h], result[t]
    }

    return strings.Join(result, separator)
}
```

And `s := partition("11001000", "|", 3)` will give you `11|001|000`.

Here is a little test:

```
func TestSmokeTest(t *testing.T) {
    input := "11001000"
    s := partition(input, "|", 3)
    if s != "11|001|000" {
        t.Fail()
    }
    s = partition(input, "|", 2)
    if s != "11|00|10|00" {
        t.Fail()
    }

    input = "0111001000"
    s = partition(input, "|", 3)
    if s != "0|111|001|000" {
        t.Fail()
    }
    s = partition(input, "|", 2)
    if s != "01|11|00|10|00" {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```