# How to print float number where decimal point is comma (,) in fmt.Sprintf

Tags: string, go, localization, string-formatting

I am printing floating point value(eg: `52.12`) like this:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%s", percentageValue, "%%")
```

Output is like `52.12%`. But I want to print it in other language than English where decimal point is comma `,`. How to do it in Go using `fmt.Sprintf`. I want output like this **52,12%** .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fmt.Printf an integer with thousands comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020308/how-to-fmt-printf-an-integer-with-thousands-comma)

Comment: The short answer (as mentioned in the question linked above) is to use https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message

Comment: The standard lib (and the `fmt` package) does not support localized text and number formatting. If you want that, take a look at the [`golang.org/x/text/message`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message) package which _"implements formatted I/O for localized strings with functions analogous to the fmt's print functions. It is a drop-in replacement for fmt."_

Answer (score 13):

The `fmt` package does not support the functionality to replace the delimiter in a floating point number.  You should instead use the [golang.org/x/text/message](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message) package, which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: I tried that package.  But it doesn't work.  Even on its front page, it uses the wrong decimal separator for Dutch.  Who are the maintainers of this package?

Comment: That package is maintained by the official Go team.

Comment: Thank you.  It turns out that `message.MatchLanguage()` does not work.  For whatever reason, `message.MatchLanguage("da")` does not return `language.Danish` (as one would expect) (or `language.Dutch` for "nl"), but rather the "und" `Tag`.

Answer (score 7):

The standard lib (and the `fmt` package) does not support localized text and number formatting.
If you only need to localize the decimal point, you may use the easy way to simply replace the dot (`.`) with the comma character (`,`) like this:

```
percentageValue := 52.12
s := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%%", percentageValue)
s = strings.Replace(s, ".", ",", -1)
fmt.Println(s)
```

*(Also note that you may output a percent sign `%` by using 2 percent signs `%%` in the format string.)*

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gpRxRIBNwmk)):

```
52,12%
```

Or with a mapping function:

```
func dot2comma(r rune) rune {
    if r == '.' {
        return ','
    }
    return r
}

func main() {
    percentageValue := 52.12
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%%", percentageValue)
    s = strings.Map(dot2comma, s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mmeqe1lt5-l).

Yet another solution could be to format the integer and fraction part separately, and glue them together with a comma `,` sign:

```
percentageValue := 52.12
i, f := math.Modf(percentageValue)
s := fmt.Sprint(i) + "," + fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%%", f)[2:]
fmt.Println(s)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IwgZXwtAXNQ).

Note that this latter solution needs "adjusting" if the percent value is negative:

```
percentageValue := -52.12
i, f := math.Modf(percentageValue)
if f < 0 {
    f = -f
}
s := fmt.Sprint(i) + "," + fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%%", f)[2:]
fmt.Println(s)
```

This modified version will now print `-52,12%` properly. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/51vCYkF2PpZ).

If you need "full" localization support, then do check out and use [`golang.org/x/text/message`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message), which *"implements formatted I/O for localized strings with functions analogous to the fmt's print functions. It is a drop-in replacement for fmt."*

Answer (score 1):

I found a library to do that, it's called humanize.
With this you can do something like this `fmt.Println(humanize.FormatFloat("00,00", 52.20))`

See in the link below the instructions:
https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by this:

```
func getFormattedValue(percentageValue float64) string{
  value := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%s", percentageValue, "%")
  return strings.Replace(value, ".", ",", -1)
}
```

I am taking float value and converting to string then replacing `.` with `,`

Comment: This is the solution I posted in my answer. I don't think we need this duplicate answer.