# GOLANG - Formatting float to currency string (with point in the thousands and comma in the decimal separator)

Tags: go, format

I have a code that formats a string to a big float:

```
formattedAmount := strconv.FormatFloat(amount, 'f', 2, 64)
```

The result of this is a float with precission of 2 after the comma, IE:

> 10000000000000.99

Now, i wish to parse this number to a currency format, as this:

> 10.000.000.000.000,99

Is there a way to parse the float as a string with that format in native golang?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to fmt.Printf an integer with thousands comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020308/how-to-fmt-printf-an-integer-with-thousands-comma)

Comment: The fmt package does not support thousands separators. As pointed in the comment above, this question has already been asked. Not sure what you're trying to do, but if it's a web app, your frontend should be able to handle the presentation side of things. Please refer to the link provided by @icza and you'll find enough information about this subject in referred the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fmt.Printf an integer with thousands comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020308/how-to-fmt-printf-an-integer-with-thousands-comma)